# Is it possible to lose magic?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I seem to have lost the ability to equip magic. In the start of the game we can equip Noctis with Fire. It can be fired like any long range weapon.  However after visiting the first tomb I removed fire and gave it to Gladius. This allowed him to cast magic every so often. However, eventually he stopped casting. I checked his gear and the fire I gave him is gone. It is nowhere to be found. Where is the fire and how can I get it back?

Am I mistaken? Is Magic more similar to an Item in that it has a finite number of uses before vanishing from inventory?

Suppose I sold my Fire magic; where could I buy it back?

Answer (score 3):

"*Is it possible to lose magic*"? Well, technically yes.

Magic in Final Fantasy 15 works different than most Final Fantasy games. Spells require crafting and, by default, each spell can be casted 3 times before requiring to be crafted again. This automatically removes the spell from your characters equipment.

To craft spells, make your way to *Elemency* in the main menu. On the right, you will have *Magic Flasks*, and on the left is your elements. Select a *Magic Flask* to begin and choose which spell you want to craft (*Fire* on the top, *Thunder* to the right, or *Blizzard* to the left). From there, you can increase the potency of the spell by increasing the number of elements used.

In order to increase the number of casts, you need craft the spell with different materiels. You can select which materials you'd like by selecting the *Item* on the bottom of the element section.

Comment: Does it matter what item I use for the bottom?  I have chosen a potion but can't complete the elemency.  I've chosen a potion cause that's all I can afford.

Comment: @Calimari328 No, it does not matter the item, but different items give different attributes; I believe potions heal the caster. After you apply the elements and items, go down to *Craft* (or however it's labeled) and it will be finished

Comment: I figured out my problem.  I would choose my item by pressing x and nothing would happen.  I didn't realize I had to press the dpad down again to actually craft.

Comment: Don't forget (as mentioned in this answer) that you do not *have* to use any items, when crafting, but the potency will not exceed 99 if you do this.  (Note that Potency between 100 and 299 turn spells into Tier 2 (Fire -> Fira) and 200+ turns them into Tier 3 (Fire -> Firaga).  Keep this in mind when giving AoE spells to teammates.

Comment: thanks @Khale_Kitha I thought the item was mandatory.  I'll try making magic without an item.